# GET not possible in esp8266 wtih AT commands

Tags: at-command, esp8266

Im trying to get temperature from website from my ESP controller. i used the same requests using IE and Fiddler they are working very fine. im doing nothing wrong also from ESP point of view.

**please find my esp request and response below.**

> ```
> AT+CIPSTART="TCP","http://myesp8266.comlu.com",80\r\n
> ```

`CONNECT`

`OK`

> `AT+CIPSEND=93\r\n`

`OK`

`>`

> ```
> GET http://myesp8266.comlu.com/temp_post.php?temps=15 HTTP/1.0\r\n
>
> Host: myesp8266.comlu.com\r\n\r\n`
> ```

`Recv 93 bytes`

`SEND OK`

`+IPD,574:HTTP/1.1 302 Found`
`Date: Tue, 09 May 2017 02:20:31 GMT`
`Server: Apache`
`Location: https://www.000webhost.com/migrate?`
`utm_source=000&utm_medium=rdr&utm_campaign=old_panel_off&static=true`
`Content-Length: 299`
`Connection: close`
`Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1`

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">`
`<html><head>`
`<title>302 Found</title>`
`</head><body>`
`<h1>Found</h1>`
`<p>The document has moved <a href="https://www.000webhost.com/migrate?`
`utm_source=000&amp;utm_medium=rdr&amp;utm_campaign=old_panel_off&amp;static=true">here</a>.</p>`
`</body></html>`
`CLOSED`

**when i use IE i receive the following for the request**

> `http://myesp8266.comlu.com/temp_post.php?temps=15`

`response ->`
`Notice: Undefined index: temperature in /storage/h9/116/1546116/public_html/temp_post.php on line 2
15`
`Temperature : Celcius`

`15 is what i expect and im receiving it good...`

**Below is the code from fiddler which im receiving good**

> `send ->`

`GET http://myesp8266.comlu.com/temp_post.php?temps=15 HTTP/1.0`
`Host: myesp8266.comlu.com`

> `response ->`

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK`
`Date: Tue, 09 May 2017 02:08:40 GMT`
`Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`
`Connection: close`
`Server: awex`
`X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block`
`X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff`
`X-Request-ID: ce6759371cbb05088c5c954aa35de737`

`<br />`
`<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: temperature in`
`<b>/storage/h9/116/1546116/public_html/temp_post.php</b> on line <b>2</b><br />
15<p>Temperature :  Celcius </p>`

where is wrong?? tried in many possible ways. but no success with only ESP8266 remaining ways working good.

please help.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first AT command establishes a TCP connection, but includes `http://` which it probably shouldn't as at this point it's not yet relevant (we're just opening a socket)

**Incorrect AT command:**

`AT+CIPSTART="TCP","http://myesp8266.comlu.com",80\r\n`

**Corrected AT command:**

`AT+CIPSTART="TCP","myesp8266.comlu.com",80\r\n`

**The next problem is your get request**

The host name should only be specified probably on the `Host` header also protocol isn't required on this line also the GET requests URL should be relative to the host I believe.

**Your request:**

`GET http://myesp8266.comlu.com/temp_post.php?temps=15 HTTP/1.0\r\n
Host: myesp8266.comlu.com\r\n\r\n`

**Corrected request:**

`GET /temp_post.php?temps=15 HTTP/1.0\r\n
Host: myesp8266.comlu.com\r\n\r\n`

Besides these 2 changes guessing that's a send length after `AT+CIPSEND` so may need to update that too it may even be possible to omit the length entirely.

Finally you've got a minor issue in `temp_post.php` which is throwing a notice you can fix this by either altering the error reporting levels or if you post some code I'll have a look :). Alternatively if you want a cheap and nasty fix prefix whatever variable is causing it with an `@` ie `@$myTemps['temperature']` (although definitely better to fix the issue)

Answer (score 0):

simply beautiful

i ve deleted `http://`

> **Corrected AT command:** and modified as you mentioned

```
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","myesp8266.comlu.com",80\r\n
```

worked like charm..

ahhh.. what a breath.. tried in all possible ways except modifying CIP start.

> 1000 thanks for resolving.

Good day dear.

Comment: You're very welcome :) If my answer was correct can you please select it as the correct answer. Also I realize formatting options can be a bit limiting at times but a message like this is best suited to a comment :). If you need help with the PHP notice still either edit the question with a bit of code or comment with the first couple of lines of `temp_post.php` and I'll take a look :)

Comment: Yes. decided as right answer tick mark. and Php i ve updated myselves (it uses just a echo reply :) so simple)... and sure in future i will have some issue with php sql programming. Actually im good at programming microcontrollers. but coming to IOT and other web http realted stuffs im very poor.(TCP IP absolutely 0). Thanks for providing your kind helping hand. Let me know if you are interested too.. i will share my simple project. Note: im not 100% working on it. whenever i get free time i used to sit and work on this stuff to feel occupied in leasure time. One day i will aplly if works good

Comment: Thanks, and you're very welcome :). When it comes to PHP and SQL SO is great just ask away when you need help :) Personally I'm the opposite I came from a web background and am learning to program microcontrollers but also have good low level knowledge when it comes to TCP/IP and HTTP. I can't commit to working on any new projects at the moment due to an injury but I try to check SO every day so if you need help just post a question or yell out :)

Comment: Great Brian... nice talking and sharings. Im sorry for your injury.. get well soon.We will keep in touch and i will share all my simple works what ive done with passwords to you if u share ur email. Just to have a look...mine is mutthunaveen@gmail.com..two weeks i ll be busy shifting to new office.. if i get time in between i will share alll..in 10 min u will understand my simple php codes.. Im from India by the way.